# Desktop app to remove metadata from FLV

Tags: video, cross-platform, metadata-editor

I need to delete some (chosen by name) metadata fields from FLV video file.

The only tool I found so far is [flvmeta](http://www.flvmeta.com/), but it seems it can only show and add but not remove metadata.

Requirements:

- Any desktop OS, preferably cross-platform.
- Command line or GUI doesn't matter.

Solutions like video editors that would require to re-encode a video stream don't suit.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but what do you mean exactly with "chosen by name"? Do you mean the names of the fields themselves?

Comment: @nidunc yes, exactly. The names of the fields themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).

The following command will remove metadata fields `title` and `author`:

```
ffmpeg -i x.flv -c copy -metadata title= -metadata author= y.flv
```

Another way is to dump metadata to file, edit and reload. [How To: Dump and Load metadata with ffmpeg](http://jonhall.info/how_to/dump_and_load_metadata_with_ffmpeg)

To inspect metadata, just run `ffmpeg -i video.flv`

To completely remove metadata, use `-map_metadata -1` <sup>([Strip metadata from all formats with FFmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/441361/strip-metadata-from-all-formats-with-ffmpeg))</sup>